# How can I prune executors' logs in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, logging, log4j, spark-streaming

I'm working on a spark streaming job which runs on standalone mode. The executors by default append the logs in `$SPARK_HOME/work/app_idxxxx/stderr` and `stdout` files. Now the problem comes when app runs for a long time say a month or more and it generates a lot of logs inside `stderr` file. I would like to rollup the stderr daily for  a week  and archive(delete) that after that. I changed the `log4j.properties` with `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender` and directed the logs to a file instead of `stderr` but the file doesn't respect the rolling and keeps growing. 
Creating a cron job to do that is also not working since spark has a pointer to that specific file and changing the name probably not working.

I could't find any documentations for these specific logs. I really appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 4):

After digging more, I finally found how to resolve the issue and I post it here so that the next person don't go through all this suffer and trial/error. 
The setting for those logs are in two different places. One in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-default.conf` add these three lines below `in each executor`:

```
spark.executor.logs.rolling.time.interval  daily
spark.executor.logs.rolling.strategy  time
spark.executor.logs.rolling.maxRetainedFiles  7
```

The other file that you need to change `in each executor` is `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh` add the following line:

```
SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="$SPARK_WORKER_OPTS -Dspark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true -Dspark.worker.cleanup.interval=1800 
 -Dspark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl=864000 
-Dspark.executor.logs.rolling.strategy=time 
-Dspark.executor.logs.rolling.time.interval=daily 
-Dspark.executor.logs.rolling.maxRetainedFiles=7 "

export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS
```

After these changes it started working properly. Hope this helps some people :)

Comment: does this work for print statements in python Udfs as well ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are in standalone mode, just export an environment is enough:

```
export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="-Dspark.executor.logs.rolling.strategy=time -Dspark.executor.logs.rolling.time.interval=daily -Dspark.executor.logs.rolling.maxRetainedFiles=7"
```

you can also refer to: http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Executor-Log-Rotation-Is-Not-Working-td18024.html

Comment: unfortunately, link isn't working anymore